# Linker error in Android Studio while compiling NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to build an NDK project with Android Studio 2.3, NDK is integrated with it, Gradle 3.3, where I am using some shared libraries(which come with NDK and also present in the device), and these shared libs are listed in CMakeLists.txt on doing "Clean Project" Gradle is successfully done with no error,

```
8:36 PM Gradle sync started
8:37 PM Gradle sync completed
8:37 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
8:37 PM Gradle build finished in 12s 541ms
```

but on running the project it gives a linker error.

```
> Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build F:\StudioPrj\Aaudio\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\mips64 --target native-lib}
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\mips64\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=mips64el-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/mips64el-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=24 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fintegrated-as -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-mips64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\mips64\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/AaudioImp.cpp.o  -laaudio -llog -latomic -landroid -lm 
"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/mips64/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/mips64el-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../mips64el-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -laaudio
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From the errors, it seems like toolchains can't link to libaaudio, but I have used 1 header file in my code coming from this .so like this

```
#include <aaudio/AAudio.h>
```

also NDK is properly showing me all available options from this module, so I don't think this .so is not linked to project. Just to confirm more libaaudio is already present at these paths(this lib comes with NDK package)

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-26\arch-arm\usr\lib
>       C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-26\arch-arm64\usr\lib
>       C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-26\arch-mips\usr\lib
>      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-26\arch-mips64\usr\lib 
>       C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-26\arch-x86\usr\lib
>      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-26\arch-x86_64\usr\lib

Comment: are you compiling the code as is when you download code ( either from android studio IDE or from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-audio-high-performance? it is set to use android-26 and clang. may you try go to your downloaded directory and rm  -fr your-dir/app/.externalNativeBuild, your-app/app/build? if it is still happens, it is a bug, will look at it. thx

Comment: I had set minSdkVersion as 24 and I think system was looking for libaaudio in API version 24 which was of course not present, on setting minSdkVersion to 26 it compiles.

Comment: thanks! DanAlbert is correct, aaudio is only supported from android-O and above.

Answer (score 1):

> --sysroot C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-mips64

You're targeting android-24, and aaudio isn't available until android-26.